# Calcular formula en textbox en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Cuento con tres TextBox.

LISTATextBox, DESCUENTOTextBox y COSTOTextbox.

`COSTOTextbox` sería igual a `LISTATextbox + DESCUENTOTextBox`.

Mi problema está en que en DESCUENTOTextBox tendría que colocar una fórmula como la siguiente: `10%-20%+5%`.

Siempre son operaciones con `%`. Y siempre sumo o resto los porcentajes.

- Ejemplo: si en LISTA tengo `100` y en DESCUENTO `-10%-10%`, COSTO debería dar como resultado `81`.

Existe alguna forma de resolverlo? Hasta ahora sólo pude trabajar con cuentas simples, pero no fórmulas en cadena.

Les dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
Private Sub DESCUENTOTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DESCUENTOTextBox.TextChanged

    Dim Numero As String
    Dim math As String
    math = Val(DESCUENTOTextBox.Text)
    Numero = LISTATextBox.Text + DESCUENTOTextBox.Text
    COSTOTextBox.Text = Numero

End Sub
```

**---- EDIT --------------------------------------------------------------**

Dejo el código final con el que pude resolver el problema. Gracias Agustin M.!

```
Private Sub DESCUENTOTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DESCUENTOTextBox.TextChanged

    Dim Descuento As String = DESCUENTOTextBox.Text

    Dim DescuentoSeparado() As String
    If LISTATextBox.Text = "" Then
        LISTATextBox.Text = "0"
    End If
    If LISTATextBox.Text > "0" Then
        Dim Lista As Double = LISTATextBox.Text

        DescuentoSeparado = Descuento.Split("%")
        'En DescuentoSeparado almacenamos el Array separado por %

        For x = 0 To DescuentoSeparado.Length - 1
            If DescuentoSeparado(x).ToString <> "" Then
                ' Recorremos el Array y dependiendo si el descuento es
                ' positivo o negativo se lo sumamos o restamos a Lista
                If Val(DescuentoSeparado(x)) > 0 Then
                    Lista = Lista + (Lista * Val(DescuentoSeparado(x)) / 100)
                Else
                    Lista = Lista - (Lista * Math.Abs(Val(DescuentoSeparado(x))) / 100)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        ' Finalmente obtenemos Costo.
        COSTOTextBox.Text = Lista
    End If
    If LISTATextBox.Text = "0" Then
        COSTOTextBox.Text = "0"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner más ejemplos de lo que se debería evaluar? ¿Son siempre operaciones con `%`, o es una pregunta más amplia? ¿Qué intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder. Siempre son operaciones con %. Y siempre sumo o resto los porcentajes.
Si en LISTA tengo 100 y en DESCUENTO -10%-10%, COSTO debería dar como resultado 81.

Comment: [tag:formulas] es para fórmulas de hojas de cálculo pero esta pregunta no se refiere a dicho tipo de fórmulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema puede ser resuelto separando la cadena que posee los descuentos con el carácter de porcentaje (**%**). Luego podemos recorrer el `array` que nos resulta de eso para aplicar los descuentos al precio de Lista, finalmente quedando un costo.

Código de Ejemplo:

```
    Dim Descuento As String = "10%-20%+5%"

    Dim DescuentoSeparado() As String
    Dim Lista As Double = 200
    Dim Dto As Double
    Dim Costo As Double

    DescuentoSeparado = Descuento.Split("%")
    'En DescuentoSeparado almacenamos el Array separado por %

    For x = 0 To DescuentoSeparado.Length - 1
        If DescuentoSeparado(x).ToString <> "" Then
            ' Recorremos el Array y dependiendo si el descuento es
            ' positivo o negativo se lo sumamos o restamos a Lista
            If Val(DescuentoSeparado(x)) > 0 Then
                Lista = Lista + (Lista * Val(DescuentoSeparado(x)) / 100)
            Else
                Lista = Lista - (Lista * Math.Abs(Val(DescuentoSeparado(x))) / 100)
            End If
         End If
    Next

    ' Finalmente obtenemos Costo.
    Costo = Lista
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Quedó perfecto. Muchas gracias!!